# Power spectral density of 2D field - Python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft, spatial

I would like to use Welch's method for calculating the power spectral density of a 2D field. There is an implementation available in Scipy, but according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) it will only work for 1D timeseries.

Is anyone aware of an implementation that would work for 2D fields?

So far I have been using the 2D Fourier transform to do the calculation, but I have heard that this method is sensitive to noise and that Welch's method is more robust.

Comment: What type of data is your "2D field"?

Comment: Currently it's just a synthetic sample from a random field. In principle, spatial data.

Comment: You can use the welch method in one dimension and than implement it for a second  time in the second dimension. The dimension is controlled by the axis parameter https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html

Comment: @GideonKogan I don't think you can take that approach, since the Welch method squares the magnitude of the Fourier coefficients. The 2D periodogram should perform consecutive FFTs, then square magnitudes for each (k,w) in the frequency domain.